# Zend Framework 2 - Invokable class as action

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, zend-framework2

Usually in Zend Framework to in the routing configuration it is specified the action and the controller that need to be use to answer a particular request.

Then in the controller class it is needed an `somethingAction` method that correspond to the action provided in the configuration.

Is is possible to use the `__invoke` method of the controller as an Action?

Otherwise, is it possible to specify any type of callable instead of an object method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is is possible to use the __invoke method of the controller as an Action?

Yes. The abstract controller's `onDispatch()` figures out [what method to call](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php#L75-L86). If you simply override the `onDispatch()` with your custom logic, you can call whatever method you want. An example (not tested):

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
    if (!$routeMatch) {
        throw new Exception\DomainException('Missing route matches');
    }

    $action = $routeMatch->getParam('action', 'not-found');
    $method = '__invoke';

    if (!method_exists($this, $method)) {
        $method = 'notFoundAction';
    }

    $actionResponse = $this->$method($action);

    $e->setResult($actionResponse);

    return $actionResponse;
}
```

This way the `__invoke()` should be called with a single argument, the action it had in the route match.

> Otherwise, is it possible to specify any type of callable instead of an object method?

Not really. ZF2 determines the controller by a `Dispatchable` interface. As long as a class implements that interface, it is an controller. The standard action controller implements the `onDispatch()` and figures out the action to call, but that is not necessary. In ZF2 it is not possible to use any callable you want.